# How to manage classes configuration and propagate it to deeper levels

Tags: php, oop, configuration, encapsulation

I have some classes that need to interact. Every class has many *options* that could be tuned to get one behaviour or another.

*(**note:** I didn't test the code so there could be some syntax error)*

*(**note 2:** I write in PHP, but I guess the question is valid for every OOP language as well)*

```
<?php

class Process
{
    protected $element;
    protected $config;
    protected $default_config = array(
        'process_path' => '/bin/command',
        'default_output_path' => '/tmp/',
        'element_conf' => array()
    );

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        $element_config = array_key_exists('element_conf', $this->config) 
            ? $this->config['element_conf'] 
            : array();
        $this->element = new Element($element_config);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->element->behave();

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

class Element
{
    protected $type;
    protected $config;
    protected $default_config = array(
        'behaviour_type' => 'evil',
        'can_kill_people' => true
    );

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = array_replace($this->default_config, $config);
        $this->type = $this->config['behaviour'];
    }

    public function behave()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ....
}

class Config
{
    // get data from config file and makes it available with a static getter/setter
}

-------------------------------

$element_conf = array(
    'can_kill_people' => false
);
$process_conf = array(
    'default_output_path' => Config::get('default_output_path'),
    'element_conf' => $element_conf
);

$pr = new Process($process_conf);
$pr->run();
```

I would like to keep the encapsulation as high as possible, so I avoided to have a direct reference into the classes to the **Config** class (the config could arrive from some other place as well).

I would like to receive your thoughts about:

- **The way is provided the configuration for the inner class** (**Element**). I would like to initialize its config at the top level
  (before calling the `run()` method); but I don't find nice the way
  the configuration for **Element** is dependant on the code from
  **Process**.
- **The way to provide configuration for a class**. Would it better to pass/set an *array* config like in my code, or
  should I pass every setting as a constructor argument, or set it with
  a *setter*?
- **Would you keep the configuration in a *protected* property, as an *array*?** Or would you assign each relevant setting to a single *protected/private* property?
  (like I did for `Element::type`)
- **What is your usual approach to manage configurations of a class?** Would you try to have class also for storing the configration? Would you prefer arrays? Or passing/setting arguments/properties directly? (this last approach, in my mind, is not so easy to maintain).
  Or even better, does any **design pattern** exists specifically for this case?

Comment: The protected attributes of Process are not used, so remove them. Process at all is actually not necessary, since it only wraps `run` for `behave`. We don't know what your code does, but try to code top-down then you see what you need. If something is getting to complex or too long lines, then split it into smaller parts. In other words, I cannot answer your questions, because I don't know what you want from your program.

Comment: Mine is not a real program; just an example to show a case. So please don't try to give a purpose. The question is not about the classes doing something; is about how to provide a configuration to them. Maybe that points you in the right thinking?
(btw I agree with splitting too complex methods/classes)

Comment: Then pass the Element to the Process. Your process is full of boilerplate code which has nothing to do with the Process. Write a new component (maybe an ElementFactory) taking all config stuff and providing a makeElement() method. This only makes sense, if you're going to create more than one Element. Read about some Design-Patterns if you want to dive into encapsulation and so on. I mostly use frameworks and Dependency Injection containers. Don't use them for small programs. It's a creational pattern.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about Dependency Injection, but still I should make more experience with that. Actually I came out with my question right while reading a book about Design Patterns :)  I will try to rely more on the Factory pattern; cause I noticed the same thing and agree with you saying that there is to much stuff in **Process** that doesn't have anything to do with it. And I was worried that the "short answer" to my question would have been: _write more classes!_

Answer (score 1):

If your process class is to be parametrized by Element object than pass an Element object as a parameter and not its parameters as a parameter. This approach also emphasize that Process class depends on Element class which is not immediately visible from Process constructor right now.

As for the array configuration - in my opinion using arrays is easy for writing but makes it hard to actually use the class, how will you know easily what settings your class support? I'd rather use either individual parameters in constructor or separate configuration class with defined properties.

How you do things inside the class itself doesn't really matter that much as long as you wrap it up in some reasonable public interface. What you want to do is keep as much stuff private as possible to keep the ability to change the inner workings of the class if necessary while maintaining backwards compatible public interface. Also keep in mind that protected is pretty much the same as public when it comes to your ability to change it without breaking backwards compatibility as protected properties and methods can be used by child classes.

One last thing - if your class really have many parameters that change its behavior then maybe you should consider whether it wouldn't be better to split these different behaviors to new classes that would extend the base class or implement its interface (whatever suits your situation better).

Comment: **1 - Process class depends on Element class which is not immediately visible from Process constructor right now:** do you mean in the constructor signature/fingerprint?

Comment: **2 - protected is pretty much the same as public:** I'm still studying about it; **protected** allows at least to inherit and to keep the scope in the extended class, while private ties you too much to the parent class. I don't say it's wrong, but just I still don't get the advantages of **private** methods/properties.

Comment: **3 - split these different behaviors to new classes:** I was inexact; the _many_ settings are more for setting flags, or paths (destination to temp files, processed files, or logs; and source path for the process to execute, or already processed files to load). It's not much related to a different behaviour but more about _tuning_ the data in input and output, or a format, or small option to the process. Not really about a complete different behaviour. (_still keeping in mind that the code has no purpose, even if it is inspired to a use case with a set of classes I had to write recently_)

Comment: @Kamafeather: 1) Yes, 2) Once you allow somebody else to use something that's only intended for the purpose of your class it makes it much harder for you to change it, because you'll have to make sure it doesn't break things somewhere else, 3) that's ok then

Comment: **1)** Would you suggest a Dependency Injection of the full (already configured) **Element** object? **2)** Yeah I understand; it's a problem of mine, cause I just still have difficulties distinguishing between what I don't want to be changed at all and what instead should be changable; so actually I follow the **protected** approach, that seems to be more flexible in case of wrong-design from a not-really-wise developer.

Comment: 1) Yes, that's basically what I said

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way to do something globally, there is a best way to do what you want (generic or not) (apply first assertion :D).

**The config defaults**

A configuration item may be mandatory or not but should always have a default value (so it could be not mandatory).
In my mind, there is 2 way to provide a default value:

1. The declarative way
   When you instanciate the configuration object, you provide all default values, but no dynamic values are possible if the source is not dynamic.
2. The "inline" way
   You provide the default value when you request the current value.

But, in fact, you could use both using your own rules.

Using these rules, you could provide a default value to the configuration of your Element. But its current configuration could be provide as a sub-config or another source... that Process can use.

**The declarative configuration**

In your source code, the configuration is declarative, this means when you develop it, you know that configuration exists and must/could/should be provided. So it doesn't matter if you use an object with private element to store your config values/format or a simple constant per config key.

In my framework, all configurations are stored as arrays in a protected member of a Config class. This is due to the fact i need genericity but i don't allow missing values in config files.

**OOP allows only OOP**

When you use OOP, use it as much as you can, an object is an instance of a class, the class is declared, you know what its contents means. You can not do generic sources if you don't use objects.